# Get the value of the context menu items

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

HTML -

```
<ul id="myMenu" class="contextMenu">
    <li class="insert" onclick ="test();"><a href="#insert">Add New</a></li>        
    <li class="edit"><a href="#edit">Edit</a></li>                    
    <li class="delete"><a href="#delete">Delete</a></li>            
</ul>
```

jQuery -

```
jQuery(document).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {    
     return false;
     });

 jQuery('.even').bind("contextmenu", function(e) {    
     jQuery('#myMenu').css({        
         top: e.pageY+'px',        
             left: e.pageX+'px'    
             }).show();    
     return false;


     });
```

Context Menu is working fine. But i need to click on any of them, and it must be directed some function. for an example

```
function  test() {
alert("Helloooo")
}
```

Here the onlick function is not working... Please help me in this issue...

I'm so passionate to learn Jquery stuff as my project entirely relies on jquery and XML

Answer (score 2):

well i guess the easiest way would be to bind the onclick event using jquery.. something like

```
jQuery('.insert a').click(function(){
  alert("handle the onclick event");
});
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Just try to move your onclick attribute to anchor element like this:

```
<ul id="myMenu" class="contextMenu">
    <li class="insert"><a href="#insert" onclick="test();">Add New</a></li>        
    <li class="edit"><a href="#edit">Edit</a></li>                    
    <li class="delete"><a href="#delete">Delete</a></li>            
</ul>
```